# DownThemAll - Escaping brackets in URLs

Tags: firefox-extensions, download-manager

Lets say we need to download a range of URLs named like so:

`http://example.com/file[1]` to `http://example.com/file[9]`

A normal range specifier: `http://example.com/file[0:9]` generates: `http://example.com/file0` to `http://example.com/file9`

And `http://example.com/file[[0:9]]` generates a single URL: `http://example.com/file[[0:9]]`

Neither gives the proper list. How would one write this pattern for DownThemAll?

Comment: so essentially you want to download all files from http://example.com/file*?

Comment: It may not be possibe to only download specific file names, however, you could always click on "URL" and sort via url, so you would see the numbered urls...

Comment: Humm... I'll see what I can find.